# Conversion of String with timezone to date

Tags: java, string, date

I have a string containing date with timezone like
2014-01-24 09.05.14 -06:00.

I need to convert this into date format as YYYYMMDD.
What is the best way in Java to convert the above string into date.

Answer (score 4):

Do it like this (requires JDK 7+):

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss X");
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
String dateString = "2014-01-24 09.05.14 -06:00";
Date date = inputFormat.parse(dateString);
System.out.println(outputFormat.format(date));
```

Comment: Getting the following error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'X'
 at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.compile(Unknown Source)
 at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(Unknown Source)

Comment: @Shitu X is new in Java 7, in older Java versions it is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is to convert the String into a Date and then use a DateFormatter (e.g. the [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)) to formate that date.

Take a look at this [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html) for further information.